# Как запросить данные от пользователя в Телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Не могу никак додуматься. Мне надо что-бы после того как пользователя попросят написать боту какое то сообщение,это сообщение записывалось в переменную. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вы не знаете, что такое оператор `=`?

Comment: Как Вы обрабатываете сообщения? Если у Вас есть какой-то код, приведите его, пожалуйста, в вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это :

```py
import telebot
#Используется библиотека pyTelegramBotAPI
import config
#Документ с токеном

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def variable_message(message):
    #Та самая переменная
    variable = message.text
    #И к примеру отправка этого сообщения обратно
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, variable)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, я вчера сам уже дошел до этого)))

Comment: @Varikk Всегда рад помочь